# Error type 3. Activity class {com.project/ com.project.MainActivity} does not exist in react native (Visual studio EMulator for Android)

Tags: java, android, react-native, visual-studio-emulator

I am new to React-Native.

I am trying to run my React-Native android project in Visual studio Emulator for Android.

My build was successful by running `react-native run-android`, but I am unable to launch the app in emulator.

It is giving me the below error:

> Error type 3. Activity class does not exist.

I tried gradlew clean and gradlew cleanBuildCache. but same error exists.

I checked the package name in below files and it is same in all 4 files.MainActivity.java, AndroidManifest.xml, build.gradle,       MainApplication.java

Am I doing something wrong? Or how can I run my app in Visual studio Emulator?

Answer (score 0):

have u opened your project in AndroidStudio?
After open in it, check for assets folder in App->src->main->assets , if not present make it.

run following command

```
 $ react-native bundle –platform android –dev false –entry-file index.js –bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle –assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

then again try to build and run it.

Comment: In my case i ran "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file App/Containers/App.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res" .but still the same error exists.